# How do I render nodes, now that node_view() has been deprecated?

Tags: entities

In Drupal 7 I frequently use `node_view()` for rendering nodes (using view modes) in blocks or pages as follows:

```
$nids = array(123,456,789);
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $node_view = node_view($node, 'teaser');
  $output .= drupal_render($node_view);
}
$build['nodes']['#markup'] = $output;
return $build;
```

`node_view()`/`entity_view()` has been deprecated and replaced by a view builder as explained in change record [Entities are now rendered by a view builder](https://www.drupal.org/node/1819308) . The information is not detailed enough for me to be able to figure out how to achieve the same result.

How can you render nodes in Drupal 8 so that the output can be used in the render array of a block or page?

Answer (score 51):

The [answer given by Berdir](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/178444) uses `entityManager`, which [has been deprecated](https://www.drupal.org/node/2549139) in favor of more specific services. This is the code I currently use.

```
$nid = 1;
$entity_type = 'node';
$view_mode = 'teaser';

$view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder($entity_type);
$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type);
$node = $storage->load($nid);
$build = $view_builder->view($node, $view_mode);
$output = render($build);
```

This code is a little more verbose than some might like; you could reduce it down to a couple lines if you really want more brevity by chaining together some methods.

```
$nid = 1;
$entity_type = 'node';
$view_mode = 'teaser';

$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type)->load($nid);
$output = render(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder($entity_type)->view($node, $view_mode));
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use `$node = Node::load($nid)` ?

Comment: Why use `render()` in the last line? `getViewBuilder($entity_type)->view` returns a [render array](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/render/arrays) that will be passed to the twig view.

Comment: @Tim I assume that depends on the context you are using this within, this is a wiki, so you are welcome to add your input. For some of my use cases I did not have the luxury of passing this directly to a twig template as a render array, rather I needed to perform the render myself. Best of luck.

Comment: If performing the render manually, for some cases, you may also like to consider the renderer service `renderRoot` or `renderPlain`, or via  `drupal_render_root($build);`

Comment: +1 Confirming this answer works on Drupal 9, 9.3.7.  And useful to know that In this answer `$output` is a `Markup` object, which has function/method `__toString()`  which returns the html markup as a string.  Why render? some ask. Answer: In my case I am displaying node  markupcontent using a standard endpoint url/controller function, called by javascript on the page. I want to update that part of the page, "in place". The javascript needs the node content in finished rendered html string therefore.  So with that example, there are some cases where rendering is needed.

Answer (score 22):

The most important part is to stop rendering yourself. You can return render arrays almost everywhere and you should do it. Combining strings like that together doesn't work anymore.

All you need is this:

```
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($nids);
// Or a use the static loadMultiple method on the entity class:
$nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);

// And then you can view/build them all together:
$build = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->viewMultiple($nodes, 'teaser');
```

Answer (score 5):

[`entity_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!entity.inc/function/entity_view/8) will be removed from Drupal 9.0.0. The following code works also in Drupal 9.

```php
$render_controller = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder($entity->getEntityTypeId());
$render_output = $render_controller->view($entity, $view_mode, $langcode);
```

Essentially, that is the code used from `entity_view()`, after I removed the part handling the entity render cache, and replaced a deprecated method that function uses.

Answer (score 3):

This did work for me (perfect for PHPUnit tests with Drupal test traits - https://gitlab.com/weitzman/drupal-test-traits):

```
$nid = 3139;
$entity_type = 'node';
$view_mode = 'bs_full_guest';

$view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder($entity_type);
$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type);
$node = $storage->load($nid);
$build = $view_builder->view($node, $view_mode);
$output = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($build);
$nodeHtml = $output->__toString();
```