# How to show entityQuery results as block

Tags: 8, entities, blocks

I use [entityQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8.6.x) to retrieve nodes related to actual content. Now I don't know how to add them to template and show them in my theme.

In Drupal 7 I used [Bean](https://www.drupal.org/project/bean) module to create blocks as entities. The module states the following, which I don't fully understand:

> As Drupal 8 supports fields on its block entities, this module is not
>   needed for new sites.

So how do I get the results of my entityQuery into blocks to afterwords use them twig templates?

Comment: Put the entityQuery in a block plugin? Otherwise I'm not sure what the question is about, this might help  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/178434/how-do-i-render-nodes-now-that-node-view-has-been-deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the above suggestion:
Create Custom Block for example `MyBlock`.

In the your **src/Plugin/Block/MyBlock.php** File. 
implement `build method` and `getNodesBuild method` to get the nodes build:

```
  public function build() {
    return array(
      '#theme' => 'mymodule_my_block',
      '#nodes_build' => $this->getNodesBuild(),
    );
  }
```

**NB:** Change the `$nids` array by the result of your Query.

```
  /**
   * This function return view_builder of list of nodes.
   * @return array
   */
  protected  function  getNodesBuild(){
    //- Replace this by the result of your Query
    $nids = [38, 39];
    //- Get the current lang
    $language_manager = \Drupal::service('language_manager');
    $language = $language_manager->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
    //- Get view_builder for node entity type
    $entity_type_manager = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager');
    $view_builder = $entity_type_manager->getViewBuilder('node');
    //- Load nodes
    $nodes = Node::loadMultiple($nids);
    return $view_builder->viewMultiple($nodes, 'teaser', $language);
  }
```

Implement `hook_theme` in your **mymodule.module**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'mymodule_my_block' => [
      'variables' => [
        'nodes_build' => [],
      ],
      'template'  => 'mymodule-my-block',
    ],
  ];
}
```

**templates/mymodule-my-block.html.twig**

```
  {{ nodes_build }}
```

Comment: I think your example code is not a good advice because

1. You should not use \Drupal:: in classes
2. As i posted below, most likely this can be solved using views

Comment: @adrum99, 1. It's OK for demonstration purpose, the scaffolding needed for DI would distract from the real issue. You can inject the services later when you want to test your module. 2. This is the correct answer for the question with the question mark "?", other than that the question is too broad, especially since the OP mentioned fieldable blocks as well. Could be the OP wants to replace nodes altogether. So there are a lot of possible answers.

Comment: @adrum99 this answer just for demo, and it's one of many approach, after that he can refactor the code.

Comment: If it's just for demo i'd at least mention that you should inject the services maybe. As the OP posted, views isn't an option due to complex relationships, so i agree with the suggested solution, with 2 small corrections: 

1. If you use $view_builder->viewMultiple() you don't need the loop in the method and neither in the template. 
2. There's no need for getNodesBuild() to be public. Should be protected.

Comment: Yeah, You are right about this two point, i have edit my answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of your query, you probably rather want to use views to build the query. Can you please post your query?

If you could use views instead of an EntityQuery, creating a block display and adding that block to your theme will probably be quicker and less custom code to maintain compared to writing a custom query and block plugin.

Comment: Views would be the preferred method - but doesn't work in this case. The relations are to complex and views seems to have limitations together with paragraphs, as pointed out in the last comment here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/261392/relation-through-paragraph-seems-to-be-exclusive