# Can't render node view mode pro-grammatically

Tags: 8, entities

I try to render an HTML data from my node view mode but unfortunately, I have some small progress.
I did some searching and modification on the others code [Here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/178434/how-do-i-render-nodes-now-that-node-view-has-been-deprecated).
I have this now.

```
$nid = 145;
$entity_type = 'node';
$view_mode = 'pdf';

$view_builder = \Drupal::service('entity.manager')->getViewBuilder($entity_type);
$storage = \Drupal::service('entity.manager')->getStorage($entity_type);
$node = $storage->load($nid);
$build = $view_builder->view($node, $view_mode);
var_dump($build);
die();
```

But when I run it I got this error

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch::getRouteMatch() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request, null given, called in C:\wamp64\www\executive-coatings\docroot\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch.php on line 127 in Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch->getRouteMatch() (line 99 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Routing\CurrentRouteMatch.php).

As I did step by step checking I got that just issue is with `$build = $view_builder->view($node, $view_mode);`

What is wrong with this code? Am I in the right way to render HTML data from a view mode?

**MORE INFO**

The Idea behind this is to get node data according to a specific view mode, then render the data to HTML format and use that HTML data in a PDF function to generate the related PDF file.

I simply use this code in one of my custom modules, that is ecc_pdf module.
as you can see I simply set a valid ID to load valid data for the test process.
My node type name is `safety_report`
this is my full view mode list 
[image]

I use Drupal 8

PHP 7.2

**For checking that I have any issue with other codes or not, I create a new basic site and apply this part of code inside a custom module but I get the same error again.**

This is my new custom test module code, This is my full module code for test.mudole file.

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
use Drupal\views\Views;
use Drupal\Core\Render;
$nid = 1;
$entity_type = 'node';
$view_mode = 'teaser';
$builder = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getViewBuilder($entity_type);
$storage = \Drupal::service('entity.manager')->getStorage($entity_type);
$node = $storage->load($nid);
$build = $builder->view($node, $view_mode);
$output = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($node);
var_dump($node);
```

This my info file

```
name: ECC TEST
description: For creating the custom TEST
package: Custom
type: module
version: 1.0
core: 8.x
```

As I said I create just a new site, and I don't have any other file in my module, I just have .mudole and .info.yml file that I mention above.
And the Article node that I test just is Drupal default.

This is the full error that logged for me

Comment: Changing view mode to a core mode like `teaser` does the code work ?

Comment: no, it shows the same error!

Comment: And leaving out `die()`?

Comment: Same result again.

Comment: The code is OK. Please add more details in which context you use it and add a full error message. As the question is written now it is impossible to connect the error message to the code.

Comment: As 4k4 has said, there is nothing wrong with your code. And the error message shows that - it's an error in the current_route_match service, which your code is not using. So you've misdiagnosed the code causing your error.

Comment: @4k4 I add some more details may give you an idea to help me to fix this.

Comment: Change `entity.manager` to `entity_type.manager`. I'm not sure if that's your problem, but `entity.manager` has been deprecated, so either way it's worth the change.

Comment: @Jaypan I try this change but nothing else, just show the same error. If it is deprecated what should I use?

Comment: As I said, use `entity_type.manager`. And if that doesn't fix your problem, then your problem is somewhere else, as the above code is fine.

Comment: @Jaypan for getting a clear result, I create a new basic site and apply this part of code inside a custom module but I get the same error again.

Comment: @Nasser where do you put your code?

Comment: @Jonh I create a simple module I updated the question with that part as well.

Comment: @Nasser, we need a full error message with a back trace, because the route match could be used in many places while rendering the node and we need to know where it was used before the error occured.

Comment: @Nasser There is nothing wrong with your code. Please provide your full of code, like where did you put code hook, controller...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
use Drupal\views\Views;
use Drupal\Core\Render;
$nid = 1;
$entity_type = 'node';
$view_mode = 'teaser';
$builder = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getViewBuilder($entity_type);
$storage = \Drupal::service('entity.manager')->getStorage($entity_type);
$node = $storage->load($nid);
$build = $builder->view($node, $view_mode);
$output = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($node);
var_dump($node);
```

You have dumped your code raw into a file. You cannot do that - your code is being called before Drupal has bootstrapped. You need to put your code into a function some hook that is called after Drupal has bootstrapped. I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, so I can't give any more info than that.

Comment: The Idea behind this is to get node data according to a specific view mode, then render the data to HTML format and use that HTML data in a PDF function to generate the related PDF file.

Comment: The problem isn't in what you are trying to do it, it's when are you trying to do it? If the code you had provided were to work, it would be run on every page load. But it won't work because Drupal is not yet bootstrapped.

Comment: In Drupal, code in modules goes in to functions called 'hooks'. Hooks are functions that are called after certain events. You cannot dump code raw into a file, as Drupal has not loaded yet, so your code will not work. You can read about hooks here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/understanding-the-hook-system-for-drupal-modules

Comment: I don't know why you just put code in file module :D.

Comment: Some hook you can test your snippet code like hook_preprocess_html, hook_page_attachments_alter, every request your code will be run.

Comment: @Jonh I do this many time just for checking my queries so faster. If I do it in a node insert hook I should create a new one each time that I want to check my code. But unfortunately, in some case, it has an issue like this one that I faced with.

Comment: If you are still using the same code, but in a hook, and still facing an error, then you should update the post with your current code and the current error.